# Prove that $\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty n^{p} (\sqrt[n]{3}-1)$ converges for $p<0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that series $\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty n^{p} (\sqrt[n]{3}-1), p \in \mathbb{R} $ converges only for $p<0$.

I know that for $p>0$ series diverges as its limit is undefined but I don't know how to tackle $p=0$ and $p<0$. I'll be thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $3^{\frac 1 n }-1=e^{\frac{\log 3}{n}}-1=\frac{\log 3}{n}+o(\frac 1 n)$ thus you have to study $\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty n^{p} \frac 1 n=\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty n^{p-1}$ because they have the same behavior.

Comment: Why is $e^{\frac{\log 3}{n}}-1=\frac{\log 3}{n}+o(\frac 1 n)$? I don't understand this step

Comment: @Art3 Because $e^x=1+x+o(x)$ for $x \to 0$. In this case $x=\frac {\log 3}{n} \to 0$.